# Unable to display mongo database with pyspark

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I imported a json file to mongo using pyspark. However, I'm not sure how to display the content from mongo once the file is uploaded.

Load json file to mongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

client =  MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
df = spark.read.format('json').load('json_file.json')

db = client['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.insert_one(df)
```

how can I get to display the content once it's written to mongo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`find()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) which returns a cursor with the records from the collection.

In it's simplest form, to display the data use:

```
print(list(db.mycollection.find()))
```